# ¿Como enviar un dato de un componente hijo a uno padre en vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Tengo una aplicación en vue.js necesito pasar el dato "nameComponent" del siguiente componente:

```
<template>
  <div class="dash">
    <fish-row gutter="1">
      <fish-col type="fixed" :width="200"><h2>{{nameComponent}}</h2></fish-col>
    </fish-row>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Dash',
  data () {
    return {
      nameComponent: 'Dashboard'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

al componente padre en este caso es App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <fish-layout class="demo">
      <div slot="header">
        <fish-row>
          <fish-col span="8">
            <h2><!--Aqui es donde quiero que valla el nameComponent --></h2>
          </fish-col>
          <fish-col span="8">
            <img alt="Vue logo" id="logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
          </fish-col>
          <fish-col span="8">
            <Search/>
          </fish-col>
        </fish-row>
      </div>
      <div slot="content">
        <router-view/>
      </div>
      <div slot="footer">
        <div id="nav">
          <router-link to="/"><fish-button size="medium" type="primary"><font-awesome-icon icon="tachometer-alt" /></fish-button></router-link> |
          <router-link to="/comunicator"><fish-button size="medium" type="primary"><font-awesome-icon icon="comment" /></fish-button></router-link> |
          <router-link to="/menu"><fish-button size="medium" type="primary"><font-awesome-icon icon="bars" /></fish-button></router-link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fish-layout>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  import Dash from '@/views/Dash.vue'
  import Search from '@/components/navbar/Search.vue'
  export default {
    components: {
      Search
    },
    data () {
      return {

      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

¿como puedo mostrar el dato del componente?

Comment: Estás instanciando el `Search` dentro de `<router-view/>` ¿Qué forma tienen tus rutas? Sería más sencillo si tu `App.vue` no tuviiera el template completo sino sólo el envoltorio seguido de `<router-view/>`, el cual tuviera el esqueleto dentro de un `Skeleton.vue` que a su vez llamara a `Search.vue` como `<search></search>`.

Comment: No termino de entender tu problema. Es un string fijo? podrias levantar un evento por ejemplo en el mount para que le pasara el mismo al padre.. Y el padre recibir eso evento. Pero si el string es siempre el mismo, no se que sentido tiene esto...

Comment: Veo que importas el componente `Dash`, pero ¿en qué momento lo usas en `App`? Sería de mucha ayuda extendieras la explicación de tu pregunta un poco más. A mi parecer, la opción más viable sería usar **scoped slots** para pasar dicha información al componente padre.